# Excel merge column by multiple matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two tables

Table 1

```
CODE1   CODE2
521R    854900511
521G    854900511
513R    889202858
```

Table 2

```
Number  CODE1   CODE2
6847.83 521R    854900511
440.84  521G    854900511
0       513R    889202858
0       513G    879202858
```

I want to Merge column `Number` to table 1. Is there a way to use `VLOOKUP` with multiple matching criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Index/Match as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd> after inputting formula)

`{=INDEX(A7:A10,MATCH(B2&C2,B7:B10&C7:C10,0))}`

Paste this in your Table 1

Comment: Do i need to format it as a table or will it work on just columns as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create a helper column in source table to provide unique identifiers for `VLOOKUP()` by concatenating individual identifiers like this:

```
=$A1&$B1
```

And then you perform `VLOOKUP()` with multiple criteria like this:

```
=VLOOKUP($B1&$C1,...)
```

Comment: this works too, but requires a helper column as indicated, generally index/match is better than vlookups and has far fewer limitations